# Routing issues in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I am developing a web application with codeigniter. I have created a folder in controllers with name "Administration". Inside this folder, i have kept all my controllers pertaining to the administration panels.

Now, i want that if any user types the url as www.mywebsite.com/administration, the user should be redirected to the respective controller whatever comes as the next segment after administration. like if user types wwww.mywebsite.com/administration/login, then login controller should be executed. Well this is a pretty obvious thing.

Now what i want is, when someone types anything www.mywebsite.com/anything_else, it should be directed to some other controller by default. I am using following routes setup:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = ''; 
$route['administration/(:any)']='administration/$1';
$route['(:any)']='fetch_pages';
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to do another approach:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = 'fetch_pages/index';
```

This solution makes you able to skip declaring the obvious `administration` route, and all other paths will be called through `fetch_pages` controller.

[Read more about 404_override](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#footer)

Depending on your needs, you may want to consider running [`show_404()`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) when you can't find data based on [uri](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

Comment: also, if there is a better approach, then please suggest. also, it would be great if you could point out the mistake in my previous approach as it wasn't working.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what didn't work for you, but I would consider trying a `$route['(.+)']='fetch_pages/$1'` instead of your given.

Comment: using the solution suggested by Miqdad Ali. Thanks everyone. I am up now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['^(?!administration).*'] = "fetch_pages";
$route['administration/(:any)']='Administration/$1';
```

I think you have created folder with capital letter "A" in Administration